# Why is TextView wrapping when gravity is set to left?

Tags: android, textview, android-wrap-content, android-gravity

I'm having an issue where my textview is wrapping a word when the gravity is set to left. I want it to just display the word without any wrapping.

A visual of what I want:

```
Currency     Balance     Held     Value
```

But this is what I'm getting:

```
C            Balance     Held     Value
u
r
...
```

Here's my XML:

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Currency" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Balance" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Held"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Value" />
</TableRow>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried that it displaying correctly. You can use `android:singleLine="true"` for every `TextView` and try it.

Comment: @Hariharan tried that, textview1 just disappeared altogether. I'm stumped as to why.

Comment: It displaying correctly. Can you post your all codes.

Comment: Use `LinearLayout` with `android:layout_weight` for each `textview`.

Comment: @Hariharan unfortunately the whole XML file is almost 2500 lines. Don't think you guys want to go through all that!

Answer (score 2):

Try the Below code. it is working perfect for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="Currency" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Balance" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Held"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="Value" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Output :**
[image]
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested below code same output as you want please try this-

```
<TableRow  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Currency" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Balance" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Held"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Value" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Yeah it displays with it centered, but I want the text on the left

Comment: @Seslyn see updated answer. Just copy and paste and see output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way hope this help you

Just add this properties `android:weightSum="4"` to your `TableRow` layout and this properties value depends on no of child you have.

Comment: tried that, didn't change anything. Thanks for the help though!